# Should I cut off severely bent stems (folded on darker line or spot) on my Peace Lily?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, damage

I left my home for 11 days and told someone else to water my Peace Lily but she forgot. When I returned the plant looked dead, lying flat and hanging around the pot. I have watered it and cut some yellow leaves, and in two to three days most of the leaves stood upright again.

Yet the stems of some of the bigger ones have bent so much that they are not uniformly bent but they fold on one point that is darker and seems to be damaged (see pic):

[image]

Shall I cut it or is there still any chance that it will regenerate? And if have to cut it, should I do it just below the bend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can this peace lily be saved?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/can-this-peace-lily-be-saved)

Comment: Is not a duplicate. The other question doesn't address the case when a stem is so much bent that it is damaged (it has a darker green line on the bent and it seems it wont stood upright again)...

Comment: -I had the option to confirm or not that it was a duplicate but it disappeared after editing the question-

Comment: I agree that this isn't a duplicate; the other question is about how to save the plant, while this one is about trimming the plant after recovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snip the unrecovered, bent stems out as close to the base of the plant, just above the soil level, as you can get without damaging any of the other stems. Keep it fed and watered and it should produce new growth without any problem. And maybe get someone else to look after your plant when you're next away from home!

Comment: Thanks Bamboo; as per your response and from what I'm seeing in the plant, it seems once the stem has this darker line around the bent, it won't "unbent" again... so I'll have to cut them. And yes, I'll definitively need to look for someone else to take care of it!

Comment: @Martec - yes, its too damaged to recover it previous position.