# How much light is too much for a Maranta Red house plant?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, sunlight

I recently added a Maranta Red to a room with large "bubble" type skylights. It sits on top of a book case and with the position of the room it DOES get hit by direct sunlight for roughly 45 minutes a day as the sun is in just right the position later in the afternoon.

My question, is this too much light for a Maranta? I got it for it's obviously vibrant colors etc, but I'm also a male bachelor suggesting I can barely care for myself let alone other things competently. It's the perfect spot for it aesthetically but I would appreciate someone more experienced saving me from potentially harming it.

I did read some articles, but they basically just reiterate that it's not a fan of direct sun light without really specifying how much is too much or too little. So here we are. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nowhere near a full sun location. It's hard to say so your best tool is observation. Signs of too much light:

- brown tips on the leaves
- leaves hanging down indicates too dry which can go hand in hand with too much light
- older plants can sometimes have nitrogen deficiencies under very high light. You would see the new leaves be a lighter green

Most likely your plant will be too dry.  Consider wicking technology outlined in [this answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/4495/499) for a different plant.