# what's wrong with my fish hook plant?

Tags: identification, succulents, aloe

I'm new to plants and am having a tough time. My aloe plants (creasing, not growing or spreading out) + fish hook plants (wrinkly and soft leaves) seem to be dying. What should I do to save them + prevent it from happening again? 
[image: aloe]

Comment: two questions, two posts

Answer (score 2):

Your aloe has too much water because there is no drainage from the bottom of the pot.  Try using a plastic pot inside the decorative pot and drain it after watering.  Chances are good it needs more light as well.  Move it as close as possible to a window.

The second plant is a [spathiphyllum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spathiphyllum).  This plant will tolerate low light for a while and should be kept evenly moist or [it will collapse](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/can-this-peace-lily-be-saved/4495#4495) and look dreadful until it is watered again.  For best performance avoid chlorinated water and low humidity.  Bugs are uncommon.